# Can I host/deploy a standalone MERN app as part of another website?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, self-hosting

(I'm fairly sure this question reflects a lack of familiarity with the tools available, but my searches didn't turn up much.)

Let's say I have a MERN project that works entirely on its own, let's call it `my-app`. When I run the server locally, it works exactly as intended - I browse to `localhost:3000` and I get what I want. What I'm looking for is a way to host that project as part of another website (that I own), such that I can navigate to `example.com/my-app` and be served the exact same content as when I browse to `localhost:3000` while hosting locally.

The actual use case here is that the project is open source, so ideally the project would be totally agnostic and unopinionated about where it is hosted. Using a subdomain (`my-app.example.com`) may be easier, but I would like to avoid it if possible. I would also like to avoid simply hosting the project somewhere else and redirecting to it - I know there are ways to redirect without changing the URL, but ideally this would work with something like `git submodule` such that the main website and the app project can all be hosted from the same server instance.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, yes, you could create a standalone MERN app and host it on another site. One method of doing so would be an iframe. You can just place the iframe within a page on the new site by setting the src to the location of the MERN app like so: `src="http://example-mern-app.com`.